# Get latitude and longitude from address at a time max 10000 in php cron file

Tags: php

I have a code for get lat & long from address and find lat , long successfully.But some address not find lat and long and skip the code.here is my code.Please help me.

```
$address = 'Street 1, City, Country'; // Your address
$prepAddr = str_replace(' ','+',$address);

$geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');

$output= json_decode($geocode);

$lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
$long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

echo $address.'<br>Lat: '.$lat.'<br>Long: '.$long;
```

Answer (score 0):

That probably means that no address with such name has been found.

To check this you can use status field in response as such:

```
if (strtolower($output->status) == 'ok') {
    $lat = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $long = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
} else {
    // return error ie. throw new Exception('No such address');
} 

echo $address.'<br>Lat: '.$lat.'<br>Long: '.$long;
```

Comment: i have check with your code but still some lat and long are set null.